# Missing 2 fields after applying the schema file puzzler

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 7.4 and creating core using the 3 files from the [gist](https://gist.github.com/ishaigor/e2a7d9aec101c4c166a6c511a99214e8) (one can download the files and save them in the directory <dir>/test/conf).

```
solr create -c test -d <dir>/test
```

[The schema](https://gist.github.com/ishaigor/e2a7d9aec101c4c166a6c511a99214e8#file-schema-xml) has 14 files, while only 12 end up in schema browser in [Admin UI](http://localhost:8983/solr/#/test/schema).

The schema file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="collection" version="1.6"
    xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <types>
        <!-- The StrField type is not analyzed, but indexed/stored verbatim. -->
        <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />

        <!-- boolean type: "true" or "false" -->
        <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" />

        <fieldType name="int" class="solr.IntPointField"  sortMissingLast="true"/>
        <fieldType name="long" class="solr.LongPointField"   sortMissingLast="true"/>
    </types>
    <fields>
        <field name="childCode" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="parentCode" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"  />
        <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"  />
        <filed name="sortOrder" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"  />
        <filed name="locked" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"  />
        <field name="status" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"  />
        <field name="filename" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"  />
        <field name="url" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"  />
        <field name="previewUrl" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"  />
        <field name="shape" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"  />
        <field name="originalHeight" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"  />
        <field name="originalWidth" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"  />
        <field name="sizes" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"  />
        <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    </fields>
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

The missing fields are 'sortOrder' and 'locked'. Based on [the documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/defining-fields.html) those are valid field names:

> The name of the field. Field names should consist of alphanumeric or underscore characters only and not start with a digit. This is not currently strictly enforced, but other field names will not have first class support from all components and back compatibility is not guaranteed. Names with both leading and trailing underscores (e.g., *version*) are reserved. Every field must have a name.

Other int fields with camel case are created such as 'originalHeight' and 'originalWidth'. I am able to go into Admin UI and add the fields manually with the name and the type from the file.

I am puzzled and would appreciate any clue to this disappearing fields mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spelling is wrong:

```
<filed name="sortOrder" ..
<filed name="locked" ..
```

Change it to `<field>` and it'll work as the other fields.